# Cannot update any attribute in the testUpdateBookOrdersShippingAddress

Tags: oracle, hibernate, connection-pooling

I have a problem about updating BookOrder. BookOrder is connected to DetailOrder via composite key according to many to many relationship.

The error is shown below.

```
May 23, 2019 2:33:48 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection 
INFO: [c3p0] Exceptions occurred while trying to close a PooledConnection's resources normally.
May 23, 2019 2:33:48 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection 
INFO: [c3p0] NewPooledConnection close Exception.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.processError(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:86)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:62)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:908)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:2005)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:642)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:255)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:622)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1076)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1101)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1062)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1316)

May 23, 2019 2:33:48 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: Failed to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@3dd18dc6
java.sql.SQLException: Some resources failed to close properly while closing com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@3dd18dc6
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:664)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:255)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:622)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1076)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1101)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1062)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1316)
```

I think there can be a session problem. Session can be automatically closed when it is needed to open.

My test class

```
@Test
    public void testUpdateBookOrdersShippingAddress() {
        Integer orderId = 48;
        BookOrders bookorders = ordersDAO.get(orderId);

        System.out.println("Update Before (ShippingAddress) : " + bookorders.getShippingAddress());

        bookorders.setShippingAddress("New Home Shipping Address");

        try {
            ordersDAO.update(bookorders);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        BookOrders updatedOrder = ordersDAO.get(orderId);

        System.out.println("Update After (ShippingAddress) : " + updatedOrder.getShippingAddress() );

        assertEquals(bookorders.getShippingAddress(), updatedOrder.getShippingAddress());

    }
```

Hibernate Class for get and update method.

```
public T update(T t) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.merge(t);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        }

        return t; 
    }

    public T get(Class<T> type,Object id) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        T t = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            t = session.get(type, (int)id);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        }

        return t; 
    }
```

Comment: `ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error` This signifies an Oracle internal network error. The standard advice is to contact Oracle Support. If your organisation does not have a Support contract you may be out of luck. Have a look in the database Alert Log for further info and dump directories for trace files. Beyond that [have a pipe at other questions on ORA-03106](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-03106) - perhaps one of those has a solution which will work for you too.

Comment: @APC I edit my post.

Comment: @APC Create , getAllList and countAll and get method are worked without any error. However, update method throws an error.

Comment: @APC I can use hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In update function of hibernate class based on generic type, I could use `session.update(t);` instead of `session.merge(t); and I could solve it.`